# Error running a php project in firefox and Chrome

Tags: php, macos, safari, xampp

I have created a php project. I am using XAMPP. When I run login page, after successful login it should redirect me to a webpage called

```
http://localhost/xyx.php
```

However in firefox it redirects me to

```
 http://localhost/localhost/xyx.php
```

However the same thing works fine in safari.On successful validation, I redirect user using following line of code:

```
header('Location: http://localhost/xyx.php');
```

Can anyone tell me what might be the issue?

Comment: Please post the relevant PHP.

Comment: have you tried same in other browser also?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar : Just tried in Chrome. It also has issue similar to firefox.

Comment: try with this `header('Location: xyx.php');`

Comment: @user1247412 have you tried the solution.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar : I tried the solution but it is not working. I get following error:
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost

Comment: @user1247412 what is the url in urlbar?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar :header('Location: xyx.php')

Comment: @user1247412 Not this just like example `http://localhost`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be enough to redirect into xyz.php..

```
header('Location: xyx.php');
```